# Testing Ad-hoc Provisioning Profile in Real Device - IOS XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

For an application that I am working on, I use parse server and the push notification property. Until now I was using a developer provisioning profile. Now I want to test the app with the Ad-hoc provisioning profile as it is said that before putting to the apple store it would be good to test it in Ad-hod. I created the profiles, and selected the ad-hoc profile in X-code under build settings>provisioning profile, and the debug info under code signing identity are set as iphone distribution. However when I run the project in a device I got the error: `process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 4481`

When I convert the profile to developer mode again in xcode, it works. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Via Xcode? If so instead create an archive and install the archive then run that

Comment: Hello Pumping Lama, is there a tutorial about how to do that? I guess I need more details. Yes I try to run via xcode.

Comment: You should be able to find tutorial easily enough (I don't have one to hand). Also you do realize you will need to generate a production push ssl certificate and upload that to the parse server and switch to using the Apple push production environment not the development environment - otherwise the pushes will not get delivered.

Comment: If you running directly from xcode using a distribution profile, it will give you the same error. To test with the distribution profile you need to test the build using testflight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For run directly in the device, you need generate Provisioning Profiles in development mode. The adhoc Provisioning Profiles can't run in the device if you not have the `device id` added.

in developer.apple

[image]

Later edit your provisioning profile and add the new device and re-generate it.

> This way is very unstable. Personally i recommend the development provisioning way.

Comment: Hi Jose, how can I add the device id?